# Change line-height depending on number of characters

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

In my React website I'd like to change the line-height property of a word I have that changes length (based on some other logic). What I'm doing is that every letter of the word is on a separate line:

```
.myWord {
  line-height: 3.9;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

outputs:

```
m
y
w
o
r
d
```

But I also need it to line up with another element next to it, so that it would always be equally tall. The current line-height is only fitting for a word that is 6 letters long.

I found a similar question on stackoverflow with a jQuery answer:

```
var cnt =  $(".tweeter_widget").text().length;
if (cnt > 10) {
  $(".tweeter_widget").css("line-height", "5px"); 
}
```

If someone could translate that into JSX or provide a different answer, I would highly appreciate.

The logic would basically be:

- If the word is 6 letters long, line-height will be 3.9
- If the word is 5 letters long, line-height will be 4.2
- ...

I only need it for 3-6 letter words so it's no problem to write them all out.

Comment: Please add a piece of JSX you already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that I am not totally sure to have understood your question but...

Let's say that we have a `MyWord` component, in relation to the length of the text given, we need to apply to the element a certain amount of line-height property.

I would first of all have a map of the length-lineHeight matches, something like this:

```
// the key is the text length, the value is the applicable line-height
const HEIGHTS = {
    5: 4.2,
    6: 3.9
}
```

If it useful, we could keep a default, just in case we missed something

```
const DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 1
```

Then, we need a simple MyWord component that only takes a `text` prop. We assign an inline style property value upon the text prop length:

```
const MyWord = ({ text }) => (
    <div
        className="myWord"
        style={{
            lineHeight: HEIGHTS[text.length] || DEFAULT_HEIGHT
        }}
    >
        { text }
    </div>
)
```

This is just an idea of mine, whether I got the question at all... I made a sample Pen... https://codepen.io/ciamiz/pen/VEXNQo

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.